# jquery if this or this not working

Tags: jquery, facebook, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I try to make an extension for Google Chrome, I user jQuery to replace Facebook like button with other text, but when I say `if(this ==='like' || 'like2' || 'like3') else if (this ==='unlike' || 'unlike2' || 'unlike3')` it's not working.

My code:
Not: I would like this for multi language .

```
var like_message = "Sarp!";

$("body").mouseover(function(){
    convertLikes();
});
convertLikes();



function convertLikes(){
    var likes = document.getElementsByClassName('default_message');
    //var butt = like_buttons[0];
    for (var i = 0; i<likes.length; i++){
    like = likes[i];
    //like_message = like.getElementsByClassName('default_message')[0];
    like_message = like.innerHTML;
    if (like_message === 'Like' || like_message === 'E p&#235;lqej' || like_message === ' Be&#287;en'){
        like.innerHTML = like_message;
    }
    if (like_message === 'Unlike' || like_message ===  'Nuk e p&#235;lqej' || like_message === 'Be&#287;enmekten Vazge&#231;'){
        like.innerHTML = "Tam";
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with just your comparison, it is more likely that people can help you better

Comment: Why would you need the first if statement?

Comment: What doesn't work? What happens instead of what you expect?

Comment: As @AlexWayne comented, please explain the exact issue. Eg: when the value of like_message is 'foo' the condition evaluates to false, I expect a true.

Answer (score 0):

You overwrite `like_message = "Sarp!"` always with the current value in your for loop. I fixed that and renamed it to `default_like_message`.

```
var default_like_message = "Sarp!";

convertLikes();

function convertLikes(){
    var likes = document.getElementsByClassName('default_message');

    for (var i = 0; i<likes.length; i++){

        var like = likes[i];
        var like_message = like.innerHTML;

        if (like_message === 'Like' || like_message === 'E p&#235;lqej' || like_message === ' Be&#287;en'){
            like.innerHTML = default_like_message;
        } else if (like_message === 'Unlike' || like_message ===  'Nuk e p&#235;lqej' || like_message === 'Be&#287;enmekten Vazge&#231;'){
            like.innerHTML = "Tam";
        }

    }
}
```

I changed your second `if` case to `else if` and you forgot to type `var` before `like`.

---

Here the same code but in `jQuery` style:

```
var default_like_message = "Sarp!";

convertLikes();

function convertLikes() {

    $('.default_message').each(function() {

        var like_message = $(this).text();

        if (like_message === 'Like' || like_message === 'E p&#235;lqej' || like_message === ' Be&#287;en'){
            $(this).text(default_like_message);
        } else if (like_message === 'Unlike' || like_message ===  'Nuk e p&#235;lqej' || like_message === 'Be&#287;enmekten Vazge&#231;'){
            $(this).text("Tam");
        }

    });

}
```

Comment: this code work for english, but not for albaninan en turkish :(
var default_like_message = "Sarp!";

convertLikes();

function convertLikes() {

    $('.default_message').each(function() {

        var like_message = $(this).text();

        if (like_message === 'Like' || like_message === 'E p&#235;lqej' || like_message === ' Be&#287;en'){
            $(this).text(default_like_message);
        } else if (like_message === 'Unlike' || like_message ===  'Nuk e p&#235;lqej' || like_message === 'Be&#287;enmekten Vazge&#231;'){
            $(this).text("Tam");
        }

    });

}

Comment: okay then please try this:
`if (like_message === 'Like' || like_message === 'E pëlqej' || like_message === 'Beğen')`

Comment: do you have any solution for this

Answer (score 0):

> I try to make an extension for Google Chrome

Dude, get some basic JavaScript knowledge first, please. (If you’re trying to develop browser extensions, you should actually *have* that already.)

> but when I say `if(this ==='like' || 'like2' || 'like3') else if (this ==='unlike' || 'unlike2' || 'unlike3')` it's not working.

You *can’t* check if a variable has one of three values this way – because the || operator has a higher **precedence** than the == operator.

So what your code actually does is a logical OR on the comparison values first, and *then* make the comparison – so basically, it’s the same as if you wrote `if( this === ('like' || 'like2' || 'like3') )` in the first place.

Since `'like'` as a non-empty string evals to true in JS, the value of the expression `('like' || 'like2' || 'like3')` is *always* `'like'` – so you’re just comparing `this` to `'like'`, and never to one of the following values in your `if` condition.

`if(this === 'like' || this === 'like2' || this === 'like3')` would be the *correct* way of doing what you actually *want*.